# problems creating Tiny URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the tinyURL using the code bellow, for some reason is not working:
Can anyone help please. I will appreciate it

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $.get("http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=google.com", function (data) {
           alert("Data: " + data );
         });
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the solution in case someone needs it.
Thank you guys for your help

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?" +
          "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" + encodeURIComponent('http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=http://google.com') +
    "%22&format=html'&callback=?",
function (data) {
    $('#output').text($.trim($(data.results[0]).text()));
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I would check for errors. You'll see them in the browser's error console. In most browsers, you can press F12 to show the console.

Answer (score 0):

You don't make simple cross-domain ajax request.

If you get data from another domain you must use `JSONP`

Comment: dbucki, could you please help me with this i am not faniliar with JSON

Comment: tinyurl does not issue front api to which you can send data from js. 

If you want use tinyurl, you must make script on server side to requested tinyurl and response data to front

Comment: but when I copy this to the url box http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=google.com  i get the tinyURL

Comment: simple get from url box it's different from ajax get. Do you use php on server?

Comment: in this case you don't get tinyurl from ajax.

Comment: Could you please tell what can  do in this situation?

Comment: the simplest way is the php script on the server that will get tinyurl, and js on front side make ajax to the script (php) and show response

Comment: @Carlos you can also use [yql](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) to get around the cross-domain issue [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kP7nZ/)